# Is using closures to emulate encapsulation a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, closures

For example, take a look at my simple implementation of a stack:

```
var MyStack = (function() {
    var min;
    var head;

    // Constructor
    function MyStack() {
        this.size = 0;
    }

    MyStack.prototype.push = function(val) {
        var node = new Node(val);

        if (typeof min === 'undefined' || val < min) {
            min = val;
        }

        ++this.size;
        if (typeof head === 'undefined') {
            head = node;
        } else {
            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        }
    };

    MyStack.prototype.pop = function() {
        if (typeof head === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error('Empty stack');
        }

        --this.size;

        var data = head.data;
        head = head.next;

        return data;
    };

    MyStack.prototype.min = function() {
        if (typeof min === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error('Min not defined');
        }

        return min;
    };

    MyStack.prototype.peek = function() {
        if (typeof head === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error('Empty stack');
        }

        return head.data;
    };

    function Node(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next;
    }

    return MyStack;
})();
```

By using this method, I can make sure that no one is able to (accidentally or intentionally) manipulate "private" fields such as min and head. I can also make use of private functions such as Node() which doesn't need to be exposed.

I have read that this will use more memory just because of the fact that it has to maintain an additional scope for each new object that is created for MyStack. Does it need so much extra memory that this way is a bad idea?

I did try to optimize it by making use of prototypes instead of creating functions every time a new object is created. In other words, I didn't include the functions as part of the constructor of MyStack.

My question is, is this poor design? Are there are any major downfalls to this methodology?

Comment: By "emulate encapsulation" do you maybe mean "implement encapsulation"? Because I don't see in what way this is not encapsulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is using closures to emulate encapsulation a bad idea?

No. Although I wouldn't consider this to be "emulation", closures *are implementing* encapsulation.

> I did try to optimize it by making use of prototypes instead of creating functions every time a new object is created. In other words, I didn't include the functions as part of the constructor of MyStack.
>
> My question is, is this poor design? Are there are any major downfalls to this methodology?

Yes, that's actually wrong. Your `min` and `head` (and `MyStack` and `Node`) variables are essentially *static*. They are defined only once, and will be shared by all instances. You cannot create two distinct stacks, they both will have the same `head` reference.

To encapulate per-instance state, you will need to declare the variables in the constructor so that they will be created with every new object. For that, you'll have to also declare all methods that need to access them ("privileged") in the constructor scope.

```
var MyStack = (function() {
    function MyStack() {
        var size = 0;
        var head = undefined;

        function checkNonEmpty() {
            if (typeof head === 'undefined') {
                throw new Error('Empty stack');
            }
        }
        this.push = function(val) {
            size++;
            head = new Node(val, head);
        };
        this.pop = function() {
            checkNonEmpty();
            this.size--;
            var data = head.data;
            head = head.next;
            return data;
        };
        this.peek = function() {
            checkNonEmpty();
            return head.data;
        };
        this.getSize = function() {
            return size;
        };
    }

    function Node(data, next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    return MyStack;
})();
```

If you want to put these methods on the prototype, you will need to make the `head` and `size` values available as properties of the instance.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that I was actually creating static fields. No wonder I was facing some issues when using my implementation. 
Now that you have refactored my code, it makes a lot more sense to me. 

So essentially, is the following the dilemma? Either have "private" fields but recreate methods each time a new object is created, or expose the fields but enjoy the memory benefits of the prototype?

Comment: @gjvatsalya Yes, exactly. Although creating methods is fairly cheap actually, you usually shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Fantastic, that's great to hear then. Thanks for pointing out the critical mistake I made.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that encapsulation is one of the principles of of Object Oriented Programming, I don't think this is a bad coding practice. Closures in JavaScript are your means of encapsulating variables and restricting access to other parts of the application.

In a lot of ways, nothing is truly secure in JavaScript. Even with a closure, those variables you want keep private are accessible via different means in different browsers. For example, in Google Chrome, you can set a break-point in the debugger and get access to any variable within the active enclosure. Although we can do a great deal within the browser to ensure security, we are still dealing with an interpreted language that is compiled on the machine running the code.

And considering your example:

`var MyStack = (function(){...})();`

If you ever work with typescript or any rapid development frameworks, you will see that this is the output coding method used to namespace objects when the frameworks compile/transpile.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. With regards to using a debugger, this means that they will only have read-only access, right? Or will they still be able to modify the value by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: Also, could you explain what you meant in your last paragraph? Are you just saying that those frameworks using the same pattern as the one I had used in my example?

Comment: @gjvatsalya They can modify anything in the debugger. When you're stopped at a breakpoint, you can double-click on any of the variables in the Scope field, and it will let you type a new value for it.

Comment: As for the last paragraph, yes. I mean that those frameworks use that same coding style. As far as the debugger, yes, you can change variables on the fly and manipulate the application. There is really not much you can do about that. You also asked about performance. The overhead for performance based on this coding style is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. 
If performance impact is negligible, then I feel comfortable writing more JS code in this methodology then.